# Laravel how to check if user is logged using database sessions

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function isLogged($cookie)
{

    $c = Crypt::decrypt($cookie);
    //how do I check using this decrypted session id if the user is logged?

}
```

I have a table sessions, there are session id, payload, lastactivity, so if the user logout, how do I check instantly using the database session manaager if it is logged?

Comment: Did you try just to check with Auth::check() if the user is logged in or not? This should work independently of your session driver.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever `Session` driver you use you don't have to think about it, you may always use `Auth::check()` to check if the user is logged in or not, for example:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
   // user is logged in
}
```